# Is there an electronic device (not a speaker) that is small and can generate single tone beep

Tags: sound

I'm new to the world of electronics and I'm working on a project where I want to create a circuit to generate a beeping sound but it needs to be as small as possible (< 6mm) to be effective in what I want it to be used for.

The speakers I was looking at are too big for what I want to do and I am having trouble finding other things to use.

Thanks!

Comment: A piezo buzzer?

Comment: They make [tiny, <4mm, surface-mount buzzers](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-devices/CSS-0575A-SMT-TR/2364642). A tiny microcontroller or oscillator (as small as 2-3 mm), plus tiny MOSFET (also as small as 2-3 mm) complete the design fitting everything but the battery into your target size. However, shopping-style questions are off-topic; I encourage you to try to design around this starting point and ask as you develop further specific questions.